# How to remedy error caused by guava: Program type already present: com.google.common.util.concurrent.internal.InternalFutures

Tags: guava, android-guava

An AAR library already uses com.google.guava.

If an app includes the following in its build.gradle:

```
api 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0-android'
```

Building the app generates the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: ...
  Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
  Program type already present: com.google.common.util.concurrent.internal.InternalFutures
```

If I do not include "api 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0-android'", the app can be built, but it has runtime error of java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when it reaches the point of using the Guava method: Iterables.find

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Since Guava 27.0](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/guava-discuss/fzjrNKOq79Y/ssJHXJBGBwAJ), `ListenableFuture` is located in separate artifact, see [the announcement](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/guava-announce/Km82fZG68Sw). You can try two things (one at a time):

1. Exclude `"listenablefuture"` module (group `"com.google.guava"`) and build your project again.
2. I don't know the AAR specifics, but it could be that `27.0-android` doesn't work with AAR, so you should try `26.0-android` instead.

Comment: Thank you! The library is our own library that uses  api 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0-android'.  The problem started when I updated Guava from 23.5-android to 27.0-android.  If I use 23.5-android in the app (the library still uses 27.0-android), the app will work.  Following your answer, the following in the app also works: compile('com.google.guava:guava:27.0-android'){
        exclude group: "com.google.guava"
    }.   This is strange because I thought the above essentially excludes the entire Guava package.

Answer (score 10):

I had to update to version 27.0.1, at the time of writing they still haven't updated the README with this new version.

```
implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android'
```